# Traverse hierarchy object c#

Tags: c#, hierarchy, traversal

If I have a Class like below. How do i traverse through it until its property SomeObjects.count = 0

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _SomeObjects = 0_ being _SomeObjects_ a `List<>`? There are several options to loop through a _List_. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sort of a vague question here, its really clear what you're having trouble with. Are you asking how to write a recursive function? Or do you need to traverse objects in a specific order? What have you tried so far?

Comment: And by _List_ I mean **Tree**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generic example of how you can traverse a composite object:

```
public static class TraversalHelper{

    public static void TraverseAndExecute<T>(this T composite, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> selectChildren, Action<T> action)
        where T: class
    {
         action.Invoke(composite);
         composite.TraverseAndExecute(selectChildren, action, new List<T>{ composite });
    }

    private static void TraverseAndExecute<T>(this T composite, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> selectChildren, Action<T> action, IList<T> invokedComponents)
        where T: class
    {
        invokedComponents = invokedComponents ?? new List<T>();
        var components = selectChildren(composite) ?? new T[]{};
        foreach(var component in components){
            // To avoid an infinite loop in the case of circular references, ensure 
            // that you don't loop over an object that has already been traversed
            if(!invokedComponents.Contains(component)){
                action.Invoke(component);
                invokedComponents.Add(component);
                component.TraverseAndExecute<T>(selectChildren, action, invokedComponents);
            }
            else{
                // the code to execute in the event of a circular reference
                // would go here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample usage:

```
public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
   var someObject = new SomeObject { 
                        Name = "Composite",
                        SomeObjects = new List<SomeObject>{
                            new SomeObject{ Name = "Leaf 1" },
                            new SomeObject{ 
                                Name = "Nested Composite",
                                SomeObjects = new List<SomeObject>{ new SomeObject{Name = "Deep Leaf" }}
                            }
                        }
                    };
   someObject.TraverseAndExecute(      
                      x => x.SomeObjects, 
                      x => { Console.WriteLine("Name: " + x.Name); }
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: @niju, Glad I could help.  You can select an answer by clicking the Check mark in the top left of the target answer post.

Comment: will this iterate through enumerable members as well?

Comment: @LuisFerrao, the `selectChildren` parameter is a delegate that selects an enumerable.  The `foreach` clause iterates through each element in the resulting enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tree-like structure; there are many algorithms for traversing it, you can [search for tree-traversal algorithms](http://www.bing.com/search?FORM=IEFM1&q=tree%20traversal%20algorithms&src=IE-SearchBox) and you'll find many of them.