# Extract objects from a nested object based on a property value and project to a new class

Tags: c#, linq, mapping, automapper

I have the following  nested input class

```
 //InputClass
public class MessageViewModel 
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public List<MessageViewModel> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to create a new instance of the following type :

```
 //Target Class
public class DestinationClass
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

for every instance MessageViewModel that has the property IsSelected = true
What is the best solution in this case? Can this be achieved using AutoMapper ?

EDIT:

lets suppose that I have the following object :

```
var vm = new MessageViewModel
        {
            Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> {
                            new MessageViewModel {
                                IsSelected = true,
                                    Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> {
                                            new MessageViewModel { IsSelected = true,
                                                                    Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> { new MessageViewModel { },
                                                                                                            new MessageViewModel { },
                                                                        new MessageViewModel { } } } } } }
        };
```

I would like to traverse it and extract and map only the MessageViewModels that have IsSelected equal to true.

SOLVED:

using the following code :

```
 public static class TraversalHelper
{
    public static void TraverseAndExecute<T>(this T composite, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selectChildren, Action<T> action)
        where T : class
    {
        action.Invoke(composite);
        composite.TraverseAndExecute(selectChildren, action, new List<T> { composite });
    }

    private static void TraverseAndExecute<T>(this T composite, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selectChildren, Action<T> action, IList<T> invokedComponents)
        where T : class
    {
        invokedComponents = invokedComponents ?? new List<T>();
        var components = selectChildren(composite) ?? new T[] { };
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            if (!invokedComponents.Contains(component))
            {
                action.Invoke(component);
                invokedComponents.Add(component);
                component.TraverseAndExecute(selectChildren, action, invokedComponents);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I managed to Iterate over my hierarchical object :

```
 var vm = new MessageViewModel
        {
            Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> {
                            new MessageViewModel {
                                IsSelected = true,
                                    Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> {
                                            new MessageViewModel {
                                                IsSelected = true,
                                                Messages = new List<MessageViewModel> {
                                                    new MessageViewModel { },
                                                    new MessageViewModel { },
                                                    new MessageViewModel { } } } } } }
        };

        var results = new List<DestinationClass>();

        vm.TraverseAndExecute(_ => _.Messages, _ => {
            if(_.IsSelected == true)
            {
                results.Add(new DestinationClass { Subject = _.Subject });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You shouldnt use underscores in C# lambdas for readability reasons. It should be a "m" for Message or better a "message". And you can refactor this with Linq Statements to transform it into a IEnumerable of DestinationClass.  Furthermore,  you can simplify the if statement to if(_.IsSelected)

Answer (score 2):

Since your class is a nested hierarchy, you need an extension method.

One with more LINQ characteristics would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T current, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenFn) {
    var working = new Stack<T>();
    working.Push(current);

    while (working.Count > 0) {
        current = working.Pop();
        yield return current;

        if (childrenFn(current) != null)
            foreach (var child in childrenFn(current))
                working.Push(child);
    }
}
```

This takes a parent object and a function that returns a list of children objects from the parent and returns all the objects flattened.

Now you can use this to produce your answer:

```
var ans = vm.Flatten(mvm => mvm.Messages)
            .Where(mvm => mvm.IsSelected)
            .Select(mvm => new DestinationClass() { Subject = mvm.Subject });
```

Comment: will this work in case I have a multi level hierarchy of Messages ? a list of lists of lists ... that have the IsSelected equal to true ? I think that this is my problem. thanks

Comment: How deep is your multi level hierarchy?

Comment: should work on a general case, n levels, that would be the best way.

Comment: You can use the Extension Method SelectMany() to flatten nested Collections. Sould return you one IEnumerable of all MessageViewModels and then you can transform them with Select into a new IEnumerable of your DestinationClass

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501096/traverse-hierarchy-object-c-sharp  that was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RaduOlteanu I re-wrote my answer to handle the hierarchy and using a more LINQ style than the `Traversal` functions.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use an IEnumerable of Message ViewModel as a constructor parameter in the DestinationClass. Then you can iterare over the MessageViewModels collection using System.Linq and select each model where the condition is true and transform it into an IEnumerable of DestinationClass.

This is just one way how you can solve this issue. If you could give us more details about your solutions architecture it would be easier for us to give you support. Greetings EnvyIT

Comment: My concern is about the nesting,  I dont know how to traverse this object, because it can have a deep hierarchy level. Please follow my edit :D